# Help understanding this dimension sheet

Tags: mechanical-engineering, modeling, cad, 3d-printing

I am trying to currently model a few parts for my custom 3D Printer. I have found some flanged lead screw nuts i'm going to use, but i'm having a hard time reading the dimension sheet. Specifically, what does "D4h11" mean? I understand D4 is as per the chart, but what's h11?[image: ,]

Answer (score 3):

h11 is the tolerance range. There's a standard shaft/hole chart based on dimension/tolerance. *(sorry about the images, I've searched on google but cannot find everything on the same image)*.

**h11** is applied to shafts, and **H11** is for holes.
With your example D4h11 is Ø48mm with tolerance of -0 to -160 microns.
The referenced part can be (48-0,000) = **48mm** (máx) or (48-0,160) = **47,84mm**(mín)

[image: Shaft/hole chart. Font: Wikipedia]*Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IT_Grade*

[image: Shaft chart. Font:http://sttechnica.blogspot.com/2011/03/tolerances-iso-tolerances.html]*Source: http://sttechnica.blogspot.com/2011/03/tolerances-iso-tolerances.html*

Comment: You should add the source of your image

Comment: Sorry joojaa, edited with the sources. I've put on another field (inside of the image I think)